# Injection point for stability analysis

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, stability

According to the [application note](https://www.omicron-lab.com/fileadmin/assets/Bode_100/ApplicationNotes/DC_DC_Stability/App_Note_DC_DC_Stability_V3_3.pdf) from OMICRON, for making good stability analysis of a converter, it is necessary to place the injection point at a certain place on the board :

[image]

[image: I do not know]

Does anyone know why we need to find a place where "the impedance looking in the direction of the loop is much bigger than the impedance looking backwards".

If you have any links to any documentations to explain it, It will be a pleasure to have it.

Thank you,

Comment: I wrote [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/665272/292884) on the subject a while back. Perhaps that can help.

Comment: Thank you this is what I looking for :)